# MySQL - How to delete from table when nested select uses that table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_1
WHERE  table_1.id IN (SELECT table_1.id
                      FROM   table_1,
                             table_2,
                             table_3
                      WHERE  table_1.id = table_2.table_1_id
                      AND    table_2.id = table_3.table_2_id
                      AND    table_3.id = 5)
```

Seems like MySQL won't let me have `table_1` in the nested SELECT. Suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't... It would, after all, execute the SELECT before executing the DELETE. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably getting this error:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'table_1' for update in FROM clause.
```

You should be able to do this using MySQL's multiple-table [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html) syntax instead:

```
DELETE table_1.*
FROM   table_1,
       table_2,
       table_3
WHERE  table_1.id = table_2.table_1_id
AND    table_2.id = table_3.table_2_id
AND    table_3.id = 5
```

The above query should work, but as a general rule I would recommend using ANSI JOIN syntax instead:

```
DELETE table_1.*
FROM   table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 on table_2.table_1_id = table_1.id
INNER JOIN table_3 on table_3.table_2_id = table_2.id
WHERE table_3.id = 5
```

Comment: @Ike - yes, that's the error I'm getting. The problem is that I need to delete multiple records, not just 1 specified by `id = `. That is why I was trying to use `IN` and a nested select.

Comment: You can delete multiple rows with the multiple-table delete syntax. Just take your nested SELECT and turn it into a DELETE. I just copied the code from your example. Please update your example if it's not representative of the actual query you are running.

Comment: Sorry, the nested select would return many table_1.id. That is why I used `IN`. Does that help?

Comment: Not really :) If you complete the example query in your question I will show you how to solve it with multiple-table delete syntax. Show me the ***actual SQL*** you are running (no "....") and I can help you.

Comment: @Ike - I modified the SQL per your request.